# Why does schema.rb update after I run db:migrate for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My understanding is that whoever created the migrations should've also updated `schema.rb`. Since I've pulled the migrations, I should've also pulled the updated `schema.rb`. However, once in a while, `schema.rb` updates after I run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

My current workflow is:

1. `git pull --rebase origin master --prune`
2. `rails s`
3. Rails tells me to migrate
4. `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
5. Realize `schema.rb` updated

At this point, I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to check in the updated `schema.rb`. I'd manually revert it through `git checkout origin/master db/schema.rb`.

So what went wrong in this case? Did a co-worker forget to run migrations after creating them? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What exactly changed in `schema.rb`? There are several options and it's difficult to answer your question without knowing what actually happened.

Comment: `schema.rb` represents your database as it is and that may or may not match up with the current state of your migrations. Maybe you ran migrations in a different order so the columns are in a different order, maybe you (or someone else) ran migrations that no longer exist so your `schema_migrations` tables have different contents. Do a `git diff` on `db/schema.rb` and see what precisely is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know schema can change after running rails db:migrate because of:

1. A co-worker did not commit the schema.rb so when you fetched and run the migrations you get the diff
2. A different DB version is running on your local machine. Based on db configuration schema may be changed accordingly.

Running git diff will help you to understand what is going.

Answer (score 4):

`schema.rb` retains two key sets of data:

1. a description of all the tables in your app database structure
2. a list of all the migrations that have been applied.

if a new developer were to join your team, they should be able to run `rake db:schema:load` and get an up-to-date database structure straight away. That's far more efficient and reliable than expecting them to run through all the migrations manually.

Running `rake db:migrate`, even if there are no outstanding migrations that need running, will always regenerate `db/schema.rb`. Most of the time you won't notice because the file will be the same – but you may get differences in whitespace formatting or column order.

The best practice (IMHO) should always be to check in the updated `db/schema.rb` in the same commit as any migrations you've added.

When fetching or pulling branches to your local machine, running `rake db:migrate` will apply whatever new migrations need to be run based on the records in your local database's `schema_migrations` table. After that, your new `db/schema.rb` *should* be the same as the one you pulled down – but if it isn't, `git diff` will show you what the difference is.

You can then make a judgement call as to what the best course of action is. If the only difference is cosmetic, I personally tend to revert the unstaged changes and leave the committed version untouched until the next migration.

All the above also applies if you have switched to a SQL-based structure file (`db/structure.sql`) by specifying `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in `config/application.rb`.